(Sin Vergüenza) - same as 'explicit' in songs?
El Comando Exclusivo - El Comandante Viejito (Sin Vergüenza) - El Makabeliko
i found this song and sin verguenza means ~ explicit content?

Un momento, no confundir sin vergüenza con sinvergüenza. Son dos cosas completamente diferentes.
Vamos primero con el caso del post y de la canción.
Sin Vergüenza: Se usa separado cuando queremos hacer referencia a una determinada forma de actuar, es decir, sin miedo ni timidez o vergüenza. Es el caso de la canción del post, lo que quieren decir entre los paréntesis es que van a hablar (o lo que sea que hagan en esa canción) sin temor ni timidez acerca del personaje en cuestión.
Sinvergüenza: Unido o junto, se usa para referirnos a una persona con determinada actitud pícara o que se mueve tan solo por intereses propios. Creo que este concepto (con la palabra unida) es al que se refiere @DGaleano en la respuesta anterior, el concepto de "shameless o scoundrel person".

so in this case this means el makabelico is EXPOSING el viejito?

Si, se podría entender de esa forma, que no va a tener vergüenza, temor o timidez.

I don't think it does mean "explicit content". Sin vergüenza means "shameless".
There is the word sinvergüenza that is used to refer to a scoundrel person.
In this case I'd think that it's just a part of the title. By being inside parenthesis it works as a subtitle.

If you google the song, pretty well all of the streaming services (Spotify, Shazam, SoundCloud, Amazon) refer to it as "El Comandante Sinvergüenza el Viejito".
